# Trouble in positioning a button on top of input text field in html using css

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this `html` file where I have placed a `input text` field and this input text field has a `button` next to it.

```
<div id="compose-message">
     <label for="new-input-message">{{gettext('Message')}}</label>
     <input type="text" id="new-input-message" class="speech-input" aria-describedby="new-input-message-help-block" name="eng-input" disabled="false">
     <small id="new-input-message-help-block" class="form-text text-muted">{{gettext('Hit enter to send message')}}</small>
</div>
```

I have these `css` elements in my `JS` and `css` files where I am specifying the size and position of input text box and button:

**FOR BUTTON**

```
element.style {
    cursor: pointer;
    top: 4.8px;
    width: 38.4px;
    height: 38.4px;
    /* position: relative; */
}
.si-wrapper button {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: none;
    font: 0/0 a;
}
```

**FOR INPUT TEXT FIELD**

```
element.style {
    padding-right: 36.4px;
}
.speech-input {
    width: 450%;
    position: relative;
    height: auto;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 0;
}
```

This creates the filed which looks like below:
[image: Button PIC]

What I want is to position the button at the end of the input text field but I am unable to position it so. What modification do I need to make it to position it that way?

**NOTE:** I am using the speech input api at this [GITHUB LINK](https://github.com/Daniel-Hug/speech-input). To increase the width of the input text field I modified the `speech-input` class in the `speech-input.css` file with below:

```
.speech-input {
        width: 450%;
        position: relative;
        height: auto;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        padding: 10px;
        font-size: 16px;
        margin: 0;
    }
```

Comment: `float: right;` maybe?

Comment: @TricksfortheWeb I tried adding `float: right` to `si-wrapper button` class but it does not change it's position

Comment: Try applying `position: relative` to the `#compose-message` and then use `position: absolute; right: 0;`

Comment: The button is not \*inside\* the input field - inputs can't have content. So positioning it relative to the input is pointless.

Comment: @TricksfortheWeb do you mean add `position: relative` to html file where I have `compose-message`?

Comment: Add `position: relative` to the `#compose-message` element.

Comment: @TricksfortheWeb I added it but it doesn't change anything

Answer (score 0):

As seen from the GitHub website, the author is using this css to position the button at the right:

```
position: absolute;
top: 0; 
right: 0;
height: 18px;
width: 18px;
margin: 0;
border: 0;
padding: 0;
background: none;
font: 0/0 a;
```

Comment: Yes that I know but the input text field that it creates is not spanned across the screen and is very small in width. That's why I added in lines to `speech-input` calss to increase its width